# Loopback email verification using REST(where is the required verifyOptions configured)

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

In loopback api explorer (localhost:3000/explorer) there is an endpoint {POST /users/{id}/verify} which I assume could be used to send verification email. In the description it is stated that

> "Trigger user's identity verification with configured verifyOptions"

I very much like to know where/how this verifyOptions is configured.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments in the user.js says: (node_modules/loopback/common/models)

````
   * Verify a user's identity by sending them a confirmation message.
   * NOTE: Currently only email verification is supported
   *
   * ```js
   * var verifyOptions = {
   *   type: 'email',
   *   from: 'noreply@example.com'
   *   template: 'verify.ejs',
   *   redirect: '/',
   *   generateVerificationToken: function (user, options, cb) {
   *     cb('random-token');
   *   }
   * };
````

You should create this object and call the user.verify function with this object. You can do this in an afterRemote hook like this:

```
//send verification email after registration
  User.afterRemote('create', function(context, user, next) {
    var options = {
      type: 'email',
      to: user.email,
      from: 'noreply@loopback.com',
      subject: 'Thanks for registering.',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../server/views/verify.ejs'),
      redirect: '/verified',
      user: user
    };

    user.verify(options, function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        User.deleteById(user.id);
        return next(err);
      }
      context.res.render('response', {
        title: 'Signed up successfully',
        content: 'Please check your email and click on the verification link ' +
            'before logging in.',
        redirectTo: '/',
        redirectToLinkText: 'Log in'
      });
    });
  });
```

This link also shows how you can configure this route:

https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user-prototype-verify

This sample shows the whole process in a sample project:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management

This link can also help you to see a sample of this process:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/590